# Preventing SVG background image from scaling

Tags: html, css, svg, image-scaling

I'm using SVG elements with masks to "knock out" or "punch out" text so that the underlying image can be shown through.  The only problem with my current set up is that when the browser window is resized, the image elements stretch and distort, rather than staying at a fixed aspect ratio/size.

I've been pouring over the svg spec and have read about preserveAspectRatio but nothing seems to work.

Here's the basic element I'm using:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
          <defs>
            <mask id="masktext1">
              <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
              <text width="100%" class="svgtext">TEXT 1</text>
            </mask>
          </defs>
          <image xlink:href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/1w3F3d130t2q1i2n2b2Y/pattern.png" mask="url(#masktext1)" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" />
        </svg>
```

Here's a JS Fiddle example. Note that the issue is visible when you resize the window horizontally.

http://jsfiddle.net/785yjwws/

Comment: @chipChocolate.py thanks for the tip!  I'm looking atviewbox now, but just to clarify, are you saying that values need to be set on the parent svg element only?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was found by reading up on viewBox as suggested by chipChocolate.py. I found [this great article by on sarasoueidan.com](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems) which helped immensely. The end solution involved setting the width and height of the image element to be the full size of the background image, setting the width and height of the parent svg element programmatically for the space, and then setting `viewBox = "0 0 [programmatic width] [programmatic height]"` which frames the content.

Comment: Always sad when you have to manipulate your svg with JavaScript because of a limitation of the protocol