# Repeating CSS background images without stretching

Tags: html, css

Is there a way create a tiled background using a repeating image without it stretching and changing size?

I have a pattern which I am using as a background. However I want this to display consistently throughout the site. Currently the pattern repeats correctly, but stretches depending on the size of the container.

Comment: By default a `background-image: url(something.png)` will be repeated and not stretched, so what do you mean?

Comment: @devius I have added a link to my question so you can see what I am referring to.

Comment: You're using a svg as background which may be your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220103/preventing-svg-background-image-from-scaling. How about just using a plain old png?

Comment: @devius that was absolutely it - thanks for your help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing SVG background image from scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220103/preventing-svg-background-image-from-scaling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference to anyone else who might find themselves with this problem...

It was because I was using a SVG. Changed to a regular image file and now everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

<style>
    div{
        background:url('https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg') repeat center;
        height:2000px;
        border:2px solid red;
        background-size:contain
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the property background-repeat

```
body {
background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

it strech because you dont change the width and height of the background when the container have a diferent size

with the value repeat:the background image is repeated both vertically and horizontally

with the value repeat-x:The background image is repeated horizontally

with the value repeat-y:The background image is repeated vertically

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is what I would usually do, however this is changing the image size depending on the container.

Comment: Then change the background-size in the two containers, that would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this css below:

```
div{
  background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
  background-size:auto auto;
  background-repeat:repeat;
 }
```