# How to stop repeating images in CSS?

Tags: html, css, background-image

How to stop repeating images in CSS? Please help,

[image: Why when I'm entering an image in CSS, the image is repeating?]

**CSS code**

```
header{
  background-image: url(originalMattress.jpg);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 450px; 
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<header>
    <p class="top-liner">over 35,000 5* reviews</p>
    <h1>This is what award-wining comfrom feels like</h1>
    <a href="#" class="main-button">Shop for mattresses </a>
    <p class="footer-text">According to capers global onsite customer reviews</p>
</header>
```

Comment: Did you try `background-repeat: none` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeating CSS background images without stretching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978553/repeating-css-background-images-without-stretching)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to set the `background-repeat` property.

To prevent the background from repeated you can set **background-repeat** to `no-repeat`.

CSS code

```
header{
  background-image: url(originalMattress.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 450px; 
}
```

Resources: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-repeat_no-repeat

Answer (score 1):

Set [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) property to `cover` this will make your background to fit in its container and [`background-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat) to `no-repeat` this will prevent your background from repeating the following is an

### Example

```css
header{
    background-image: url(originalMattress.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 450px; 
}
```

```html
<header>
    <p class="top-liner">over 35,000 5* reviews</p>
    <h1>This is what award-wining comfrom feels like</h1>
    <a href="#" class="main-button">Shop for mattresses </a>
    <p class="footer-text">According to caspers global onsite customer reviews</p>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS `background-repeat` is what you're looking for. If you want the background image not to repeat at all, use `background-repeat: no-repeat;`.

There are also other options, so I'd recommend checking out [The MDN documentation about the `background-repeat` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat)

Good luck!